# PHP form redirect to different page depending on rating user submits

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect

I have a testimonial form that allows users to submit a review and they are re-directed to a landing page once they submit the form. There is a section where the user can select a rating from 1-5. If the user selects a rating of 3 or less, I would like for them to be redirected to a different page.

I don't quite know where to start on would really appreciate any insight on how to do this.

```
    <a id="addreview" name="addreview"></a><h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add New Customer Review</h2>
<div class="systest">
    <form name="addform" action="gex-international-final.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onSubmit="javascript:return validatefrm();">
    <table width="555">

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Rating *</td>
            <td class="select">
                <select name="rating">
                    <option value="">Select
                    <option value="5">5 Excellent
                    <option value="4">4
                    <option value="3">3
                    <option value="2">2
                    <option value="1">1 Very Bad
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr> 

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></br></br><input type="checkbox" name="share_testi" /> I give permission for GEX International to share this Customer Review on their website *.<br/><br/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" class="button" name="Add" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><i>* Required field</i></td>
        </tr>       
    </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help, I appreciate anyone even taking time to look at this!

Comment: `if(condition) == 'something' { do something }`

Comment: You should post your PHP code as well.

Answer (score 2):

When sending the value of rating to your php page, just analyze what the value is and redirect using a switch statement.

```
$rating = $_POST['rating'];
if($rating <3) { redirect to the appropriate page here}
```

Or use a switch statement:

```
switch($rating){
case (3):
    redirect here;
    break;
}
```

and do that for all of the cases you wish to examine

Answer (score 1):

Create a php page with the following code and define the url of this in the action=""

```html
<?php

if($_POST['rating'] <= 3){
  header('Location: http://www.example1.com/');
} else {
  header('Location: http://www.example2.com/');
}

exit;
```